# Android Device can't able to connect with Profiler Window

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to get performance analytics of my game using Profiler so I have exported build with Autoconnect Profile setting enabled.

After this process build installed within an Android device but it can't able to run the game, it just displaying black screen nothing else. Profiler can't able to connect with the connected Android device, I was getting this kind of list within Unity profiler:

[image]

Now android device showing just black screen and profiler not moving ahead, it just remains connected with Editor only.

I have tried to connect and disconnect my Android device multiple time but nothing changed in this. Please give me some suggestion into this so I can start my debugging process.

I have already gone through this post:
[Profiler window](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerWindow.html)

Comment: Still my Autoconnect Profiler build not working in Android build without that its working fine - what is the solution for me?
Android device just showing black screen - no unity logo splash screen nothing else happening.
After spending few minutes, I require to press Home button of device to close the game.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to build in DevelopmentBuild enabled to be able to attatch profiler

[image]

Comment: This is an obvious thing so I have already done this. Because of only this reason within the device, I was getting black screen nothing else. If I do normal build then game working properly in Android device.

Comment: you can try reducing your project - i.e. start new project - see if you can attatch the debugger there. if yes - start adding your project back in